# Shell Scripting: how to use part of the file path as the file name?

Tags: shell-script, files, rename, filenames

I have a group of directories, each containing exactly 1 jpeg image, like so-

```
/psds/folder1/image.jpg
/psds/someotherfolder/picture.jpg
/psds/yetanotherfolder/thumbnail.jpg
```

What is the appropriate way to rename the jpegs to the name of their containing folder? What I want is:

```
/psds/folder1/folder1.jpg
/psds/someotherfolder/someotherfolder.jpg
/psds/yetanotherfolder/yetanotherfolder.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below commands inside `/psds` directory.

```
for f in ./*; do
    if [ -d "$f" ] ; then
        cd "$f"
        mv *.jpg "$f.jpg"
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

If you have 3 folders inside `/psds` directory like below,

```
/psds/folder1/image1.jpg
/psds/folder2/image2.jpg
/psds/folder3/image3.jpg
```

After you run the above command, the files would be renamed as,

```
/psds/folder1/folder1.jpg
/psds/folder2/folder2.jpg
/psds/folder3/folder3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) constructs `${VAR#PREFIX}` and `${VAR%SUFFIX}` to obtain the value of a variable with the specified prefix or suffix stripped off. If PREFIX is a pattern, the shortest matching string is stripped; with `##` or `%%`, the longest match is stripped instead. These constructs are available in every sh-type (Bourne/POSIX) shell, not just bash.

If the value of `VAR` is a path like `/path/to/directory/file`, then `"${VAR%/*}"` is the directory containing the file and `"${VAR##*/}"` is the file name without the directory part. Note that `"${VAR%/*}"` is only correct if `$VAR` contains at least one `/`, and `"${VAR##*/}"` only if `VAR` doesn't end with `/`. There are also utilities called `dirname` and `basename` which are more reliable in this respect. Similarly `${VAR##*.}` is the last extension.

```
for x in /psds/*/*.jpg; do
  dir="${x%/*}"
  mv "$x" "$dir/${dir##*/}.jpg"
done
```

As usual zsh has a slightly cryptic but short and sweet way. The [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function is convenient to mass-rename files.

```
autoload -U zmv   # put this in your .zshrc
zmv '/psds/(*)/*.jpg' '/psds/$1/$1.jpg'
```

Another approach using [history expansion modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) on parameter expansion:

```
zmv '/psds/*/*.jpg' '$f:h/$f:h:t.$f:e'
```